# Remove function malfunctioning in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

My function to remove nodes from a doubly linked list is adding (overwriting?) values to the list, which appear when the list is printed.

Code for the main, remove and print functions is listed below. The expected output and correlations between the current code and its output are shown below too.

#### Code for main

In main, the add function is called, and the integer in the parameter is added as a node in the linked list. The add function works, as does the print function.

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList aList;

    aList.add(3);
    aList.add(10);
    aList.add(1);
    aList.add(7);
    aList.add(9);
    aList.add(12);
    aList.printAscending();
    aList.printDescending();
    aList.remove(3);
    aList.remove(1); //The integer to be removed with this line ends up in the output
    aList.remove(7);
    aList.remove(12);
    cout << "remove operations should be complete" <<endl;
    aList.printAscending();
    aList.printDescending();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Code for remove function

```
bool LinkedList::remove(int val) //parameter contains value to be removed
{
    bool removed = false;
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;

    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr)
    {
        if(curr->data == val)
        {
            if(curr == head)
            {
                head = head->next;
                curr->next = NULL;
                delete curr;
            }

            else if(curr != head && curr != tail)
            {
                Node * previous = curr->prev;
                Node * following = curr->next;
                previous->next = following;
                following->prev = previous;
                curr->next = NULL;
                curr->prev = NULL;
                delete curr;
            }

            else if(curr == tail)
            {
                tail = tail->prev;
                curr->prev = NULL;
                delete curr;
            }
            removed = true;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return removed;
}
```

#### Code for print functions

```
//Prints from head to tail of list
void LinkedList::printAscending() const
{
    Node* curr = head;
    cout<<"\nascending: ";
    while(curr)
    {
        cout << curr->data << " ";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    cout <<'\n';
}

//Prints from tail to head of list
void LinkedList::printDescending() const
{
    Node* curr = tail;
    cout << "\ndescending: ";
    while(curr)
    {
        cout << curr->data << " ";
        curr = curr->prev;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

#### Expected output

```
ascending: 3 10 1 7 9 12
descending: 12 9 7 1 10 3
remove operations should be complete
ascending: 10 9
descending: 9 10
```

#### Actual Output

```
ascending: 3 10 1 7 9 12                  //correct
descending: 12 9 7 1 10 3                 //correct
remove operations should be complete      //correct
ascending: 10 9 0                         //last number, 0, is incorrect
descending: 9 10 1                        //last number, 1, is incorrect
```

If the call in `int main` to remove the integer 1 `aList.remove(1)` is replaced with `aList.remove(999)`, the integer 999 appears in the actual output on the descending print instead of 1. However, the integer 0 is appended to the ascending print at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the undefined behavior that Beta pointed out, you have a problem with both your special cases for head and tail. Running this through a debugger and inspecting the values in your list after each deleted would have shown you what is going wrong.

This code:

```
        else if(curr == tail)
        {
            tail = tail->prev;
            curr->prev = NULL;
            delete curr;
        }
```

does not do anything with the `next` pointer of the second last element. This means your second last element (which then becomes the last element) has a `next` pointer that points to freed memory.

To fix it, you need to set the second last element's `next` pointer to null. Something like this:

```
        else if(curr == tail)
        {
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
            curr->prev = NULL;
            delete curr;
        }
```

But wait! There is (almost*) no guarantee that the previous element existed (i.e. in a 1 element list), so you need to check that the new tail is not NULL.

```
        else if(curr == tail)
        {
            tail = tail->prev;
            if (tail != NULL)
               tail->next = NULL;
            curr->prev = NULL;
            delete curr;
        }
```

*Actually if this was a single element list, you would not reach this code, you would have already gone through the "head" if test code, which has a similar problem in that it doesn't change the second node's `prev` pointer.

So you need to also do the same sort of test in the "head" if test code.

Once you have done that, you might find that you can rearrange the tests to get rid of repeated code.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer to the issue with the descending print.

Answer (score 1):

After you delete `curr`, you then dereference it:

```
curr = curr->next;
```

This is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: How do you dereference `curr` after deletion?

Comment: @0x1000001: *You* dereference it like this: `curr->next`

Comment: What is incorrect about dereferencing `curr` in that manner? i.e, why does it result in undefined behaviour and what is the fix?

Comment: @0x1000001 Mind walk the loop and pretend your list is populated. Notice your removal loop each and every conditional block ends with `delete curr;`. Now look at the first statement executed AFTER all those conditional blocks: `curr = curr->next;`. *Undefined behavior*. Also, that isn't the only defect. Ex: for a single node list, you clear head, but tail remains set, now housing a dangling pointer; another bug.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Not dereferencing `curr` causes the program to stop before the `remove` function during runtime

Comment: You should not dereference `curr` **after the node is deleted**. You should either delete the node you found and then `break` out of the loop, or you search on if you didn't find anything. `if (curr->data == val) { delete the node and break out of the loop } else curr = curr->next;`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, that answered my question and fixed the problem.